# (laravel) Two ORDER BY clauses and a LIMIT

Tags: php, sql, laravel

This is some sorting:

1. I want to list 20 best posts based on "views".
2. then, sort it based on "created_at".

How to do it?

Heres my current code (which work, but doesnt sort by "created_at"):

```
$this->data['today_post'] = 
Posts::orderBy('views', 'desc')
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->whereRaw('created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')
->limit(20)->get();
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/multiple-orderby-on-query

Answer (score 0):

You can write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem

```
$this->data['today_post'] = 
Posts::orderBy('views', 'desc')
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
->limit(20)
->get();
```

Also add `use Carbon\Carbon;` at the beginning of your controller.

Comment: Doesnt work. You see from my title that my problem is not the "date". My problem is the sorting. I want to sort two times. First sort by views limit 20. Then sort by time (desc).

Comment: @dobieme The code I provided works fine in my system. Please have a look your table structure.

Comment: Yes, it DOES work, but doesnt sort by "created_at" :(

Answer (score 0):

Get a collection from database first

```
$x = Posts::whereRaw('created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')->orderBy('views', 'desc')->limit(20)->get();
```

Then sort the collection

Descending:

```
$this->data['today_post'] = $x->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

Ascending:

```
$this->data['today_post'] = $x->sortBy('created_at');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply sort the result collection. Keeping your code, add the following:

```
$this->data['today_post'] = $this->data['today_post']->sortBy('created_at');
```

Comment: Nice! Would you mark it as solution? Would be great as it is my first correct answer :)